# nested for loops python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Background on the project: 
I'm working on a simple program that will assist in calculating water flow in a sprinkler system's clock. I need to iterate through each station on the clock (i as iterator) and each type of sprinkler on each station (j as iterators).

The Issue: 
I've done what I believe to be a correctly nested for loops, but I'm very very new to python. what's happening is that my i iterator is just preforming the first thing asked of it and skipping the second for loop entirely.

Code:

```
for i in range(0,thisClock.stations):
  thisStation = Station()
  thisStation.setTypeNumber()
#this for loop sets all  the sprinkler types in thisStation
  for j in range(0, thisStation.intSprinklerTypes):
    thisStation.setType(j)
```

I've also uploaded the full code on github here: https://gist.github.com/SJWPrincess/ca0f76782ba80fd1e5c52cc776bcba0b

I put the objects into the main file on github so you could see it all in one place.

tl;dr: why is my program skipping this second for loop entirely and just returning the final numbers?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It seems like you create a new `thisstation` in each iteration of the loop and then do nothing that would preserve that `Station` _outside_ of the loop.

Comment: Also, you should really use a dictionary for lines 101 through 182...

Comment: the thisStation object is meant to only exist for a short time while it calculates the flows for a singe station, then deleted and recreated each time the loop repeats

Comment: thanks, I'll make it into a dictionary to save time/space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you define each station `thisStation = Station()` in your Station constructor, you seem to set `intSprinklerTypes = 0` so it is just looping from 0 to 0

based on skimming through your code I believe you should also call `thisStation.setSprinklerNumber()`

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks. I knew it was just something like that. I've made a few versions of this and I guess I just didn't catch all of my changes.